# Find the inner most text with javascript (jquery) regardless of number of nested elements and replace it

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

If I have this:

```
<a href="#" id="the-link"><em>any random text</em></a>
```

Or this:

```
<a href="#" id="the-link">any random text</a>
```

Or this:

```
<a href="#" id="the-link"><em><div id="foo"><span>any random text</span></div></em></a>
```

I would like to capture the text "any random text" and then replace it.

How can I do this with jQuery? If not with jQuery, just regular javascript?

Comment: +1 for starcraft, my favorite game.

Comment: This is part of the DOM, or a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this recursively. It's pretty simple:

```
function replaceTextNodes(node, newText) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        // Filter out text nodes that contain only whitespace
        if (!/^\s*$/.test(node.data)) {
            node.data = newText;
        }
    } else if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
            replaceTextNodes(node.childNodes[i], newText);
        }
    }
}

replaceTextNodes(document.getElementById("the-link"), "NEW TEXT");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a:contains(starcraft)').html('starcraft 2');
```

Edit for comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mqhR/2/)

```
$('a').find(':only-child:last').html('starcraft 2');
```

Comment: What if the text could be anything?

Comment: @Amir - see fiddle example for more details

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this question: [select deepest child in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787924/select-deepest-child-in-jquery)

Looks like you need to find the deepest child and then call `.html('new string')` or `.text('new string')` on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var link = $('#the-link');
var inner = link;
while(inner.children().length > 0)
     inner = inner.children();

inner.html('whatever');
```