# How do I change deepest TD to a color with javascript/jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Say I have a table:

```
<table id="#myTable">
    <tr>
        Section 1
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    Sub 1
                    <td>Sub2</td>
                    Sub3
                    <td>Sub 4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>

        <td>Section 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I make a jQuery selector for a function that finds the td containing `Sub4` and changes its color to red without affecting the background color of all the other ones?

I tried:

```
$("#myTable td:contains('Sub 4')").css('background','red');
```

But it appears to think that the outer table also catches the event. How do I get a reference to just the innermost td?

Comment: you might wanna check your mark-up again. i tried to edit but couldn't understand it

Comment: possible repeat question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787924/select-deepest-child-in-jquery

Comment: Erm... as far as I can tell that markup is invalid.  you should only have other elements (like `<td>` and `<th>`) within a `<tr>` but I see you have the text "Section 1" directly before the first `<td>`?  Fix that problem first...

Comment: `id` should be `"myTable"` not `"#myTable"`. You are missing `<td>`s too

Comment: oh duh, not sure how i missed that.  it should be id="myTable"  (your jquery selector looks right?)  but also the markup itself is sorta weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned an id in wrong way

```
<table id="#myTable">
```

should be

```
<table id="myTable">
```

If this is your table

```
<table id="myTable" class="cls" border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>Section 1</td>
        <td>Sub 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub2</td>
        <td>Sub3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Section 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

then you can use

```
$("#myTable tr td:contains('Sub 4')").css('background','red');
```

to apply red background color to only td containning "Sub 4".

A fiddle is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XU6Wc/1/).

Answer (score 0):

By deepest, I'm guessing you actually mean the LAST td in a particular row:

```
$('#mytable tr td:last').css('background', 'red');
                 ^^^^^-- add that.
```

Comment: This is correct if he wants last, but his looked right if he wants the td containing 'Sub 4' (regardless of ordinal position)