# Find the deepest and the last li in any li blocks in a ul li list using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list in HTML. There are several nested ul and li.When I click on a li, I want to find a deepest item in that li tag that has no ul tag inside and the li is the last item of that groups.
example [follow this link for example](http://s22.postimg.org/6le7x4mtt/image.png)

Here is my [HTML](http://pastebin.com/vEAPAYDm) code.

Here is my approach.

```
$('.liclk').click(function(){
    $(this).find("li").last().css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

My solution is selecting last li but not the deepest.

I am beginner in jquery.

Comment: How many possible levels? Always 3, or could it be

Comment: In your html example what is the deepest element you want to select in each situation?

Comment: No,I am looking for a general solution. That should work in any level.

Comment: OK cool ill knock something up....

Comment: <li class="item-iii liclk">III, when I click this, <li class="item-5-2">5.2</li> this should mark. @AlexChar

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259029/using-jquery-is-there-a-way-to-find-the-farthest-deepest-or-most-nested-child

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `while` to keep looking for a descending `ul` and when it can find no more, select the last list item within and apply CSS:

```
$('.liclk').click(function(){
    var $current = $(this).find('ul'),
        $desc = $current;
    while($desc.length){
        $current = $desc;
        $desc = $current.find('ul');
    }
    $current.find('li').last().css('background-color' ,'red')
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6mq8v6s/5/)

Comment: George really nice approach but take a look here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ax4ggv2/)

Comment: @AlexChar Removed `.last()` from `.find('ul')`.

Comment: @A.Wolff You refer that i'm missing a closing `li` or I am missing something else?

Comment: @AlexChar Ya you were just missing closing LI but in fact that's valid HTML (closing LI optional) if i'm not wrong, so my bad  EDIT: indeed it is: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/syntax.html#optional-tags

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick...

```
    $('.liclk').click(function() {

        var el = $(this).find("ul:last-child").find('li:last-child').css("background-color", "red");
    });
```

Comment: Your solution is also marking the unnecessary li. I just need to mark the deepest.
http://s21.postimg.org/gyjcri2vb/sol1.png
Please see the image..if I click on item II it should only mark item 3. and if i click on item III it should mark only item 5.2.

Comment: By deepest, do you mean the last li, inside the last ul of the ul that has been clicked?

Comment: Yes. thats what exactly I want. btw thanks @AdamJeffers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are after the element which is last last item with the greatest depth (so if there are two items with equal depth but found in different `ul`'s you want the last one). You could loop through all `li`'s that don't have a `ul` and save the last one with the greatest quantity of parents.  Once you've gone through everything just apply your CSS.

```js
$('.liclk').click(function() {
  var parentCount = 0;
  var $deepEl;
  $(this).find("li:not(:has(ul))").each(function(index, me) {
    if ($(me).parents().length >= parentCount) {
      parentCount = $(me).parents().length;
      $deepEl = me;
    }
  });
  $($deepEl).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level-1">
  <li class="item-i liclk">I</li>
  <li class="item-ii liclk">II
    <ul class="level-1-1">
      <li class="item-a">A</li>
      <li class="item-b">B
        <ul class="level-1-1-1">
          <li class="item-1">1</li>
          <li class="item-2">2</li>
          <li class="item-3">3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii liclk">III
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="item-4 ">4</li>
      <li class="=item-5 ">5
        <ul class="level-2-1">
          <li class="item-5-1">5.1</li>
          <li class="item-5-2">5.2</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="item-5-2">5.3</li>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```