# jQuery select or hide deeply nested div within a div with a class

Tags: jquery, nested, selector

I'm looking to hide a deeply nested div (with a class or ID name) within a container div with only class name. The container div is generated by an application so I cannot set an ID on it. I don't know exactly how many levels the div is generated so I cannot use a path - because that path sometimes changes depending on the page generated.
It's almost that I need to use a loop or something.

Here's what I have

```
<div class ="container">
   <div class ="level1">
     <div class = "level2">
        <other nested  divs and html here...>
                 <div class = "levelN" id="idLevelN">
                      content to hide 
                         <more divs and html here..../>

                 </div>
        </other nested  divs and html here...>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the div with class = "levelN" id="idLevelN".

I tried all kinds of things but I give up. I tried to use find(), filter(), etc... Help? Thanks

Comment: Can you give us any identifying attribute?

Comment: class = "levelN" id="idLevelN"

Comment: Is it levelN or is N a placeholder? If it's levelN you could do this `$('.levelN#idLevelN').hide()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.children()` selector to filter all elements that are children of your selected element.

You can also use `.parents()` to check the `div` with the `container` class is valid (is a parent).

Like:

```
   if ($( '#idLevelN' ).parents('.container').length){
     $( '#idLevelN').children().hide();
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2ah8vbo/1/)

Comment: @TheProfiler I dont think this is what you asked. you said you have no idLevelN. you said you wanted to fined the deepest nested div inside a div with class which is what my answer is all about. this answer trustst on idLevelN but you dont have it

Comment: No I didn't say the deepest div, I just say that's it's deep and don't know how many level. Mark C's suggestion worked for what I needed. Thanks everyone - Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to hide a deeply nested div (with a class or ID name)
>   within a container div with only class name.I don't know exactly how
>   many levels the div is generated

Assuming you have this :

```
<div id="SearchHere">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div >aaaaa</div> /* you want this*/
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787998/859154) :

```
jQuery.fn.deepestDiv = function()
 {
     var $target = this.children(),
         $next = $target;
     while ($next.length)
     {
         $target = $next;
         $next = $next.children();
     }
     return $target;
 }
```

Now :

```
  $("#SearchHere").deepestDiv().css('color','red')
```

[image]

http://jsbin.com/kedobuyumo/3/edit

Comment: Sorry please don't assume that my div is last. There may be other divs within that div. Thanks

Comment: @TheProfiler So which div you want to hide ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just access this by ID since IDs are unique for a page.

```
$('#idLevelN').hide()
```

However, I realize that in practice this is not always the case so you might need to use the class instead.

```
$('div.container div.levelN').hide()
```

Comment: I need to make sure my div gets hidden only when it's within the div with class ="container" . Otherwise I want to leave it alone.