# Only applying hover effects to deepest selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs as such:

```
<div class="hover-effect">
   <div class="hover-effect">
      <div class="hover-effect">
         <div class="hover-effect"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="hover-effect">
    <div class="hover-effect"></div>
</div>
<div class="hover-effect"></div>
<div class="hover-effect"></div>
```

And I'm trying to accomplish a hover effect on only the deepest element if it is the one being hovered. Currently it also applies the effect to the parent elements. How would I go by avoiding this?

Comment: Try https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be possible using Javascript

see this : https://jsfiddle.net/eszujrwm/

```
$(".hover-effect").each(function(){
    if( $(this).find(".hover-effect").length == 0 ){
        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass("hovered");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
         $(this).removeClass("hovered");
    });
    }
})
```

This code selects all .hover-effect elements, and for every one of them see if it have a child with class "hover-effect" if no It's the deepest element so we add a mouseenter/leave event

In CSS, we define a class "hovered" which contains style for onhover:

```
.hovered{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was topic about deepest element [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787924/select-deepest-child-in-jquery/3787998#3787998)

Following this answer, Gerald Fullman wrote jQuery plugin called [.deepest](https://codepen.io/geraldfullam/post/jquery-plugin-deepest) which, i think, can help you.

I can't test it right now, but i think it will be like:

```
$(dokument).ready(function() {
  $('.hover-effect').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).deepest('.hover-effect'); // ...
  });
});
```

Try to avoid use stopPropagation, because of potential problems. Read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:not()`, `:has()` to select element which do not have a specific selector as a child node

```js
$(".hover-effect:not(:has(.hover-effect))")
.hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("deepest")
});
```

```css
.deepest {
  background:purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover-effect">
  not deepest
   <div class="hover-effect">
     not deepest
      <div class="hover-effect">
        not deepest
         <div class="hover-effect">deepest</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="hover-effect">
  not deepest
    <div class="hover-effect">deepest</div>
</div>
<div class="hover-effect">deepest</div>
<div class="hover-effect">deepest</div>
```