# Affecting only the hovered children without the parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

The following code adding a red shadow on every DOM element on hover, how can i mark only that element what is under the cursor?

```
$( "html *" ).hover(function() {
      $( this ).css('box-shadow','inset 0 0 3px red');
    }, function() {
      $( this ).css('box-shadow','none');
    }
  );
});
```

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eapo/7Lyt9qeb/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select deepest child in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787924/select-deepest-child-in-jquery)

Comment: no, i have totally different question. updated to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What about nested elements? The cursor can be over more than one at a time.

Comment: @showdev this is my problem.

Comment: As I understand it, you want to select the *deepest* element *directly* under the cursor. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to take a look at [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)

---

Using the `mousemove` event, the `target` is what you are after

```js
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
  // clear "hovered" class
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("hovered");
  for(var a=elems.length-1; a>=0; a--){elems[a].classList.remove("hovered");}

  //add "hovered" class to target
  e.target.classList.add("hovered");
});
```

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  outline: 1px solid;
  font-size:0px;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
}
div.hovered{
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
body{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't see any connection with my question in this answer!?

Comment: @eapo did you even look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint ? Combine it with mouse coordinates and you have your element

Comment: i want without cursor detection, because i don't use mouse, only if there is no other choice.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover hover is exclusive to a "pointing device"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `:hover`, I suggest adding two delegated event listeners:

- A `mouseenter` event listener to detect when an element enters an element. It doesn't bubble, so it will only be invoked on the deepest hovered element.
- A `mouseout` event listener. This event happens even when the mouse moves from an element to a descendant.

```js
$("html").on('mouseenter', '*', function() {
  this.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0 0 5px red';
}).on('mouseout', '*', function(e) {
  this.style.boxShadow = '';
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
}
div {
  min-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no, i want to select parents to, but only those what is the deepest in the selection. https://jsfiddle.net/eapo/7Lyt9qeb/3/

Comment: @eapo Please define "deepest in the selection"

Comment: i want to mark only that element what is under the cursor with js

Comment: nice trick with visuals, but i can't use to select that DOM. But this can be the other question. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not needed for this use the css selector last-child with hover

```
body:last-child:hover {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

**Edit**
I misunderstood your question this is not possible with just css here is a jQuery selector to get the most deepest element.

```
$('body *:not(:has("*"))');
```

Comment: `body *:not(:has("*"))` does not conform to the CSS Selectors Level 4 proposal.